# How to highlight everything between a set of braces in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I know there is always the old fashioned way of holding down the left mouse button and dragging down, but for instance is there a method similar to (and of course this doesn't actually do it but it **should** in my opinion) holding down left mouse button and pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>?  What I'm trying to do is highlight many lines of code with the press of a button or 1 click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put the cursor on on the left or right had side of a curly brace you can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> to select all code in the block.  It will also select the curly braces.

This work using the opening or closing curly brace.

I have tested this and it works with MSVS 2013 and MSVS 2015

As an added bonus if you use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> on an opening or closing parentheses it will select all code between and including the parentheses.

Comment: Which version of VS does that apply to? It doesn't seem to work in VS 2010.

Comment: @Logicrat I can go back to MSVS 2013 and it works with that.

Comment: oh wow thank you so much it works indeed on VS 2013 thanks again

Comment: @anarchyistheanswer No problem.  I just found out it works with () as well.  I added that tidbit into the answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

Click at the top of the lines and shift click at the bottom. Its not one click but it is better then holding down the mouse and scrolling.